Neural Network In R (Response not generating)
I am running the code below for Neural Network in R. I have already installed TensorFlow which is working fine. I am facing Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) :  KeyError: 0 while running the response(). I think it is because of the inputs shape of response. The inputs are LogVol and Network. Both have the same shape i.e. TensorShape([None, 1]). Yet I am facing the above Error. How to resolve this issue?
# My Code:
# Required Package
library(tidyverse)
#install.packages("keras")
library(keras)
library(reticulate)
library(ggplot2)
library(cluster)
#install.packages("ClusterR")
library(ClusterR)
library(readxl)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

# Data

# Sample Data
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/cxkqQRgY.png)

dat=readr::read_csv("freMTPL2freq.csv") # Data is an CSV file

str(dat)
for(i in seq_along(dat)){  if(is.character(dat[[i]])){dat[[i]] <- factor(dat[[i]])}}
dat$ClaimNb <- pmin(dat$ClaimNb, 4)
dat$Exposure <- pmin(dat$Exposure, 1)


## NN
#To do: crate the following matrices
# - Design Matrix for continuous variables
# - Matrices for the categorical variables
# - Matrix for offset


MM_scaling <- function(x){ 2*(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)) - 1}

dat_NN=data.frame(ClaimNb=dat$ClaimNb)
dat_NN$DriveAge <- MM_scaling(dat$DrivAge)
dat_NN$BonusMalus <- MM_scaling(dat$BonusMalus)
dat_NN$Area <- MM_scaling(as.integer(dat$Area))
dat_NN$VehPower <- MM_scaling(as.numeric(dat$VehPower))
dat_NN$VehAge <- MM_scaling(as.numeric(dat$VehAge))
dat_NN$Density <- MM_scaling(dat$Density)
dat_NN$VehGas <- MM_scaling(as.integer(dat$VehGas))

str(dat_NN)
summary(dat_NN)


#Test Split
learn_idx <- sample(1:nrow(dat), round(0.9*nrow(dat)), replace = FALSE) 

learn <- dat[learn_idx, ]
test <- dat[-learn_idx, ]

n_l <- nrow(learn)
n_t <- nrow(test)

learn_NN=dat_NN[learn_idx,]
test_NN=dat_NN[-learn_idx,]

Design_learn <- as.matrix(learn_NN[ , -1])
Design_test <- as.matrix(test_NN[ ,-1])

Br_learn <- as.matrix(as.integer(learn$VehBrand)) - 1 
Br_test <- as.matrix(as.integer(test$VehBrand)) - 1

Re_learn <- as.matrix(as.integer(learn$Region)) - 1
Re_test <- as.matrix(as.integer(test$Region)) - 1

Vol_learn <- as.matrix(learn$Exposure)
Vol_test <- as.matrix(test$Exposure)

LogVol_learn <- log(Vol_learn)
LogVol_test <- log(Vol_test)

Y_learn <- as.matrix(learn_NN$ClaimNb)
Y_test <- as.matrix(test_NN$ClaimNb)

# Step 2: Neural Network 

# Step 2.1: Hyperparameters initialization

# the dimension of the 1st hidden layer
q1 <- 25 
# the dimension of the 2nd hidden layer
q2 <- 20
# the dimension of the 3rd hidden layer
q3 <- 15
# the dimension of the embedded layer for "VehBrand" and "Region"
qEmb <- 2 
# number of epochs to train the model
epochs <- 1000 
# number of samples per gradient update
batchsize <- 10000 

# Step 2.2: Input layer

# Input layer for continuous features
DesignShape <- ncol(learn_NN) - 1 # the number of the continuous predictors

Design <- layer_input(shape = DesignShape, dtype = 'float32', name = 'Design')

# Input layer for categorical features

Br_ndistinct <- length(unique(learn$VehBrand)) # number of vehicle brands = 11
Re_ndistinct <- length(unique(learn$Region)) # number of regions = 22

VehBrand <- layer_input(shape = 1, dtype = 'int32', name = 'VehBrand')
Region <- layer_input(shape = 1, dtype = 'int32', name = 'Region')

# Input layer for Exposure (as the offset)
#LogVol <- layer_input(shape = 1, dtype = 'float32', name = 'LogVol')
LogVol <- layer_input(shape = 1, dtype = 'float32', name = 'LogVol_Input')
#LogVol <- layer_input(shape = 2, dtype = 'float32', name = 'LogVol_Input')
Vol <- layer_input(shape = 1, dtype = 'float32', name = 'Vol')
# Step 2.3: Embedding layer

# Create embedding layer for categorical predictors (dimension: qEmb = 2)
# Vehicle Brand: 11 -> 2
# Region: 22 -> 2

BrEmb = VehBrand %>%
  layer_embedding(input_dim = Br_ndistinct, output_dim = qEmb, input_length = 1, name = 'BrEmb') %>%
  layer_flatten(name = 'Br_flat')

ReEmb = Region %>%
  layer_embedding(input_dim = Re_ndistinct, output_dim = qEmb, input_length = 1, name = 'ReEmb') %>%
  layer_flatten(name = 'Re_flat')


# Step 2.4: Main architecture and Output layer
# Main architecture with 3 hidden layers
Network <- list(Design, BrEmb, ReEmb) %>% layer_concatenate(name = 'concate') %>%
  
  # 1st hidden layer
  layer_dense(units = q1, activation = 'tanh', name = 'hidden1') %>%
  
  # 2nd hidden layer
  layer_dense(units = q2, activation = 'tanh', name = 'hidden2') %>%
  
  # 3rd hidden layer
  layer_dense(units = q3, activation = 'tanh', name = 'hidden3') %>%
  
  # provide one neuron in the output layer
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'linear', name = 'Network')


# Output layer to combine the main architecture and the offset layer (Exposure)
Response = list(Network, LogVol) %>%
  
  # add the exposure and the last neuron
  layer_add(name = 'Add') %>%
  
  # give the response
  layer_dense(units = 1,
              activation = 'exponential',
              name = 'Response',
              trainable = FALSE,
              weights = list(array(1, dim = c(1,1)), array(0, dim = c(1))))


# Step 2.5: Model configuration and fitting

# Model assembly
model <- keras_model(inputs = c(Design, VehBrand, Region, LogVol_Input), outputs = c(Response))

summary(model)

# Model configuration
model %>% compile(
  loss = 'poisson', # set poisson deviance loss function as the objective loss function
  optimizer = 'nadam'
)

# Model fitting by running gradient descent method to minimize the objective loss function
{ 
  
  t1 <- proc.time()
  
  fit <- model %>% fit(
    
    list(Design_learn, Br_learn, Re_learn, LogVol_learn), # all predictors
    Y_learn, # response
    
    verbose = 1, # verbose = 0 silences the progress bar for the process
    # verbose = 1 shows the fitting process, incl. learning loss and validation loss, epoch by epoch
    
    epochs = epochs, # epochs = 1,000
    
    batch_size = batchsize, # batchsize = 10,000
    
    validation_split = 0.2 # 20% as validation set
    
  )
  
  print(proc.time()-t1)
}

# Predicted value of the claim numbers
learn$nn0 <- as.vector(model %>% predict(list(Design_learn, Br_learn, Re_learn, LogVol_learn)))
test$nn0 <- as.vector(model %>% predict(list(Design_test, Br_test, Re_test, LogVol_test)))


dev.loss(y = learn$ClaimNb, mu = learn$nn0, dpois0)


# Code where Error is generated:

Response = list(Network, LogVol) %>%
  layer_add(name = 'Add') %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1,
              activation = 'exponential',
              name = 'Response',
              trainable = FALSE,
              weights = list(array(1, dim = c(1,1)), array(0, dim = c(1))))

# Error while running Response(): 
Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) : 
  KeyError: 0
Run `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details.

# Error Details:
Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) : 
  KeyError: 0
Run `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details.
> reticulate::py_last_error()

── Python Exception Message ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kusha\OneDrive\DOCUME~1\VIRTUA~1\R-TENS~1\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\merging\add.py", line 92, in add
    return Add(**kwargs)(inputs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\kusha\OneDrive\DOCUME~1\VIRTUA~1\R-TENS~1\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\kusha\OneDrive\DOCUME~1\VIRTUA~1\R-TENS~1\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\merging\base_merge.py", line 84, in build
    if not isinstance(input_shape[0], tuple):
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
KeyError: 0

── R Traceback ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
    ▆
 1. ├─list(Network, LogVol) %>% layer_add(name = "Add") %>% ...
 2. ├─keras::layer_dense(...)
 3. │ └─keras::create_layer(...)
 4. └─keras::layer_add(., name = "Add")
 5.   ├─base::do.call(keras$layers$add, c(list(inputs), dots$named))
 6.   └─reticulate (local) `<python.builtin.function>`(`<named list>`, name = "Add")
 7.     └─reticulate:::py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named)
See `reticulate::py_last_error()$r_trace$full_call` for more details.
> reticulate::py_last_error()$r_trace$full_call
[[1]]
list(Network, LogVol) %>% layer_add(name = "Add") %>% layer_dense(units = 1, 
    activation = "exponential", name = "Response")

[[2]]
layer_dense(., units = 1, activation = "exponential", name = "Response")

[[3]]
create_layer(keras$layers$Dense, object, list(units = as.integer(units), 
    activation = activation, use_bias = use_bias, kernel_initializer = kernel_initializer, 
    bias_initializer = bias_initializer, kernel_regularizer = kernel_regularizer, 
    bias_regularizer = bias_regularizer, activity_regularizer = activity_regularizer, 
    kernel_constraint = kernel_constraint, bias_constraint = bias_constraint, 
    input_shape = normalize_shape(input_shape), batch_input_shape = normalize_shape(batch_input_shape), 
    batch_size = as_nullable_integer(batch_size), dtype = dtype, 
    name = name, trainable = trainable, weights = weights))

[[4]]
layer_add(., name = "Add")

[[5]]
do.call(keras$layers$add, c(list(inputs), dots$named))

[[6]]
(function (inputs, ...) 
{
    cl <- sys.call()
    cl[[1L]] <- list2
    call_args <- split_named_unnamed(eval(cl, parent.frame()))
    result <- py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named)
    if (py_get_convert(callable)) 
        result <- py_to_r(result)
    if (is.null(result)) 
        invisible(result)
    else result
})(list(<environment>, <environment>), name = "Add")

[[7]]
py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named)


Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) : 
  KeyError: 0" while running code for response()

